# Generate gradient like the image

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

How can I generate a gradient like this image?

[image]

This is the closest I've got so far, but it is not yet the same:

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top right, #ff9bb4, #ff507b, #ff7a2d, #f55a00 ) ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried `rotate` instead of `skew`?

Comment: this my help you http://www.gradient-scanner.com/

Comment: I think a rotate in addition to the skew. (the corners of the original picture are not 90 degrees).

Comment: The big problem is not the rotation, but the colors.

Comment: also i think this not a radial but 2 linear gradient

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could go at this by layering semi transparent gradients:

CSS

```
.grad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.outer {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,83,21,0.21) 0%,rgba(254,55,112,0.87) 100%);
}

.inner {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,83,21,0.5) 0%,rgba(254,55,112,0.87) 100%); 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='outer grad'>
  <div class='inner grad'></div>
</div>
```

If you need it, the rotation in the image above can be achieved with `transform: rotate(10deg)` rather than the skew.

Answer (score 0):

To create the gradient, this could be helpful for you:

[Gradient generator](https://mycolor.space/gradient)

If you would like to have the border as well, I would set the gradient as the background of a div and set the border of the div the way you want.

Created a pen: https://codepen.io/Raphael_Bucher/pen/wyQRYr

HTML

```
<div class="gradient-wrapper">
<div>
```

CSS

```
.gradient-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #fa9049, #ff8153, 
  #ff7260, #ff656e, #fe597e);
  transform: skewY(-4deg);
 -moz-transform: skewY(-4deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
```